# how create if for option in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create if for option in select? The code works, it is necessary to code only worked for option = 5

```
<select id="select<?php echo $product['id_product'];?>" name="status_id" class="form-control" onchange="changeFunction(<?php echo $product['id_product'];?>)">
    <?php foreach ($statuses as $status) { ?>
        <option id="option<?php echo $product['id_product'];?>" value="<?php echo $status['id_product_status'];?>"
            <?php if ($status['id_product_status'] == $product['id_product_status']) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>
            <?php echo $status['name_product_status']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
        <textarea id="onchange<?php echo $product['id_product'];?>" style="visibility: hidden" "></textarea>
</select>
```

```js
function changeFunction(item) {  
    if ($("#option" + item).val == 5) {
        var selectOption = document.querySelector("#onchange" + item);
        selectOption.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not get your question. Please rephrase

Comment: If I understand right, you want something to happen only if `value=5` is selected. Right?

Comment: I need create if for option=5, when you select option number 5 - selectOption.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this, though you don't need to pass "item" as parameter to achieve this. When you select an option, a change event is triggered on select. So you can bind a change event for this particular requirement. Upto you.

```
function changeFunction(item){

     if($("#select"+item).val() == 5) {

         var selectOption = $("select option:selected");
         selectOption.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible');
      }
  }
```

Comment: @ultimatum check if your this code adds value as 5 on your option. value="<?php echo $status['id_product_status'];?>

Comment: I have $status['id_product_status']; = 5

1 на модерации

2 продается

3 продан

4 в архиве

5отклонен

Comment: Rework on your these values. Not good for anyones health. Unreadbale.

Comment: working!
if($("#select"+item).val() == 5) {
Thank you

Comment: @ultimatum reputations are not enough to approve edits.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this code :**

```
function changeFunction(item){
 if($(this).val() == 5) {
     $(this).css('visibility': 'visible');
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined(…)

Comment: comment the css part and then test again

Comment: working!
if($("#select"+item).val() == 5) {
Thank you